# Number of distinct sums possible for this card question?

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $8$ cards with number $10$ on them, $5$ cards with number
>   $100$ on them and $2$ cards with number $500$ on them. How many
>   distinct sums are possible using from $1$ to all of the $15$ cards?

This first time I looked at this question it seemed quite simple, but the more I work on it, the trickier it gets. I am beginner, who is trying to master combinatorics.

How do I approach this question?

Initially I came up with an answer of $8\times5\times2=80$, but I definitely feel that there is something more to it.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Note:  regardless of the typo, the formula is wrong because using all five $100's$ is the same as using one $500$.

Comment: @lulu yeah it was a typo. Corrected. Anyways, I am getting no where with this question. For a fact now I realised with your comment that my approach is definitely wrong. Well, you have any thoughts on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Oh, your basic idea is fine, you just need to be more careful.  First of all, I think it's better to start with the product $9\times 6\times 3$ since you can take none of a given type.  Then you must subtract $1$ since we exclude the empty sum, and (harder) you have to subtract the duplicates.  Happily, there aren't that many duplicates.

Comment: As a general suggestion, when you have the method down, try it on a smaller combination.  Say we had three $5's$ and two $10's$.  Same idea...you have to subtract duplicates, but now the list is so small that you can check your formula by hand.

Comment: As an alternate approach, roughly speaking you can get every multiple of $10$ from $10$ to $1580$ but you can't get $90,190, \cdots,1490$.  I'd suggest doing it both ways to check your work.

Comment: @lulu really appreciate the help. I will work on the above suggested methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the fact that $100\times5=500$.

Instead of considering $2$ cards numbered $500$, we could consider $2\times500=1000$ as $10\times100=1000$, i.e., we consider $10$ cards which are numbered $100$.

So, the total cards are : $8$ cards numbered $10$ and $15$ cards numbered $100$.

Now the task at hand is to compute the number of possible sums we could get using *at least* $1$ card.

There are ($8,7,6...,0$) i.e., 9 possibilities for cards which are numbered $10$.

And there are ($15,14,...,0$) i.e., 16 possibilities for cards which are numbered $100$.

That is, $$9\times16 = 144$$ possibilities.

Again, considering the fact that question asks to consider that *at least* $1$ for the sum, that is, we have to exclude the case where we don't pick a card at all, the answer is $144-1=143$ distinct sums possible!

Comment: I am quite amazed by the approach. I was stuck with the problem for more than hour, your explanation cleared all my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

There are 9 ways of choosing 0 or more 10s i.e [0,8]

There are 6 ways of choosing 0 or more 100s i.e [0,6]

There are 3 ways of choosing 0 or more 500s i.e [0,2]

So total no. of sums possible = 9x6x3.

But we don't want 0 sum and duplicate sums.

We can see that duplicate sums are only possible in the below two cases:

1. **5** 100s and **0** 500s = **0** 100s and **1** 500 = 500 (we
   get 9 duplicate)
2. **5** 100s and **1** 500 = **0** 100s and **2**
   500s = 1000 (we get 9 duplicate)

Final answer = 9x6x3 - 1 (for zero case) - 18 (for duplicates) = 143